# iOS UIDatePicker "Time" label locale / language not working

Tags: ios, swift, locale, uidatepicker

Is there any way to change the language/locale of the label with "Time" string on `UIDatePicker`? This is my date picker configuration:

```
datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
datePicker.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
```

And it is displayed as on the screenshot:

[image: UIDatePicker]

As you can see the "Time" label is still in English but I expected it to be in German. Is there any way to fix that or maybe at least hide this label?

Comment: Did some testing locally and so far this looks like it must be a bug in iOS, recommend reporting it at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: A possible workaround would be to use `.date` for the `datePickerMode` and have a separate button to adjust the time, similar to how the iOS Reminders app works. Depends on your UI though.